# Lua spread operator on an array

Tags: arrays, lua, spread

Does lua have a spread operator when you are passing a variable to a function?

For example, I have an array `a` and I want to pass this to another function, say `string.format`. If I just do `string.format(a)` then I get

```
bad argument #1 to 'format' (string expected, got table)
```

I tried `local f, e = pcall(string.format, t)` without any luck.

Comment: It sort of looks like the thing you'd want to look into is variadic arguments. `string.format` takes in a single param, a string type. Unless you make a function of your own for this you may run into issues. I made an example but am unsure if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Essentially what it does is makes a function that concats each element regardless of type into a string value. Not very pretty, but works on a table iteration. And anything else, for that matter. Strings, numbers, lists.

Comment: @JamesWhyte I mean you can do `string.format('Hello %s', 'there')` that would return `Hello there`

Comment: @JamesWhyte I basically have a logger that does that; converts complex object types to string. But I also want to be be able to format them too. So I can do `logger.info('User with id %s is %s', userId, table)`

Comment: I made an answer that might be worth a look over? I learned that string format increases bounds for args the more `%s`'s you have. What you could do is go something like `local paramLength = #t`, and then iterate over a variable that is your params to concat even more strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kousha. I was tinkering about and stumbled upon a function you might interesting.

In version 5.1 of Lua, `unpack` was available as a global function. In 5.2, they moved it to `table.unpack`, which makes a lot more sense. You can call this function using something like the following. `string.format` only takes in a single string *unless you add more things in the format parameter*.

```
-- Your comment to my question just made me realize you can totally do it with unpack.
t = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
string.format("%s %s %s", table.unpack(t)); -- One Two Three

-- With your implementation,
-- I believe you might need to increase the length of your args though.
local f = "Your table contains ";
for i = 1, #t do
    f.." %s";
end
string.format(f, table.unpack(t));
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this is not working in the way I want it. Let me update my question.

Comment: Ignore that, I had typo! Thanks!

Comment: Oh thank goodness! My heart skipped a beat thinking I misinformed you. Best of luck with your scripting, my friend. And thanks for the mark! :D